# is it possible to use a variable to name another variable?

Tags: python

here is what I want to do:

```
b=1
har1=42
print(f"har{b}")
```

I want it to display 42

I have tried a few things, but I haven't managed to get it to work

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use either globals() or locals() and construct the key string.

```
b=1
har1=42
globals()['har'+str(b)]

def f():
    b=1
    har1=42
    print(locals()['har'+str(b)])

f()
```